# Definitive way to find the minimum colours required to colour a graph?

Tags: graph-theory

Cherry Red wishes to colour all the circles in the diagram (shown below) so that for each circle, there is exactly one circle with the same colour joined to it.
What is the smallest number of colours that Cherry needs to complete this task?

When I tried this I got an answer of 4, but I didn’t investigate much further as I wondered whether there is a more technical way (instead of just trying an arrangement) to be sure that you have the smallest possible number. So my question is whether there is a method to be certain you have found the smallest number of colours required?

[image]

Comment: In general the graph colouring problem is NP-complete. So there is no known polynomial time algorithm for determining the chromatic number of a graph.

Comment: Oh ok, that seems disappointing haha. So there is no method except checking manually?

Comment: Hard problems are hard problems. Closed formulas for chromatic formula are known for many classes of graphs such as forests, chordal graphs, cycles, wheels, and ladders, which can be evaluated in polynomial time. But the general problem is NP-complete, unfortunately.

Comment: @Math1000 But this isn't the chromatic number.  Each vertex is adjacent to exactly one vertex of the same color.

Comment: @saulspatz I realize that now, after reading the question more carefully. Is there a name for this problem in particular?

Comment: @Math1000 I've never heard of this problem before.  The first thing I notice is that not every graph has such a coloring because the pairs of like-colored vertices give a perfect matching (one-factor) and not every graph has a one factor.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

I can't speak to your broader question, but this graph can be done with two colo(u)rs.

Comment: Ok, nice to see a smaller colouring, which is obviously the smallest for this graph! I have a feeling that this type of graph can always be done with two colours actually (for example if you just added another layer, I think you can do that with just 2 as well).

Comment: How is this a two-colouring? I see multiple instances of adjacent vertices with the same colour...

Comment: @Math1000 Read the question again.  ^_^

Comment: @MatthewDaly Oh, this is not the usual question of graph colouring. I am not sure that this is a well-studied problem then; I certainly have never seen it before.

Comment: @Math1000 Yeah, it's like choosing a perfect matching such that "contracting on that matching" gives a graph with minimal chromatic number.  But different matchings lead to different contractions.